# Problem passing variables to useQuery in ApolloClient 3

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I am using apollo client version 3.7.14 in a Nextjs project, I am trying to pass "extra variables" to a query so the backend can use them, but it seems that this funcionality is not working with apollo client 3, in apollo client 2 I can pass as much variables as I want and they are sent even if they are not preset in the query.

How can I pass extra variables, not present in the query, in Apollo client 3? For this problem i cant pass this variables in the header.

As an example I will be using this query:

```
gql` query GetUsers { getUsers { status result{data{allDataHere}}]`
```

and i will try calling it using this:

```
const responseData = useQuery<any, any>(queryHere, {client:client, variables:{data:{data1:01, data2:02, data3:03}},...
```

But after executing this I can see that the variable "data" is not use/sent.

I am hoping to find a solution to sent extra varaibles to the backend because they are not used in the query but they need them to verify the user and other data. I cant pass this information as a header so I need to find a workaround this.

Comment: Your query does not contain any $variable in it's declaration.

Comment: I believe that unused variables are stripped out before transmission to avoid variable injection (a potential security risk). Why can't you use headers? That's how authentication is normally handled.